# Concatenate two fields on Dataloader.io

Tags: dataloader.io

I have two columns Street and country on my CSV. I'm using Dataloader.io to upload them into Salesforce. Can I concatenate these two fields on the Dataloader.io itself before inserting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apex Data Loader or Data loader.io does not support data transformations like concatenation of columns in your case. You need to use the excel CONCATENATE function to combine two or more columns.

Comment: Thank you! Ill use that function in the excel sheet itself.

Answer (score 0):

Jitterbit does data transformation as part of the mapping process. Suggest switching to that, if this is a one off, then would just make modification in Excel.

Comment: We already have the license for Dataloader.io . Have to go foreard with it.